# How to make resources move along a path to the agent

Tags: anylogic

Im working on my model and I have customers going through a system.

At one point in the system my customers need service and I have a `resourcePool` to take care of the service. I currently have moving resources (**cars**) that go to my customers, service them, and then return home. Currently my resources (the cars) are jumping between nodes but not moving along a path I created.

How can I animate my resources so they move along a path from their home location (rectangular node) to my customer's location (rectangular node)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moving along paths to work in AnyLogic, it is always a prerequisite that:

- origin,
- destination, and
- moving Agent (here the ressource)

are all located on Nodes, connected by Paths and in the same network.

Make sure that the Home Location of your Ressource is connected via paths to the Locations (Queue and Delay) defined in your Service block. In the field *Destination is* of your Service, try to set "Network Node" and put your RectangularNode instead of the Agent.

[image: Screenshot of Service Properties]